# How can I chat (by mikrofon) on linux debian

Tags: linux, debian, gmail, skype, chat

I would like to talking with other people on skype, but I can't because the other person uses linux debian. Unfortunatelly the skype isn't supported in debian, therefore we can't talk eachother.
We looked for any other alternatv solutions (for example facebook or gmail), but the other person can't download the neccessary plugins because uses linux debian.
Anybody can show an alternavit solution inspite of skype/facebook/gmail?

Comment: Google Chrome with Talk plugin should work on Debian. Skype also has a Debian version.

Comment: Can you send a link, because we didn't find it?

Comment: [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/) - download the `deb` archive, [Skype](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/). Install `deb` with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in the right directory. In Chrome, when starting a Hangout you will be prompted to install the Talk plugin (also a `deb` package).

Comment: I'm sorry. I have made a mistake. Not Debian the linux is cinnamon.

Comment: Skype is [supported on Debian](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)

Comment: Yes, I know (yet), but the Cinnamon is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype is supported for Debian,:

just choose,

[image]

and he we are.

[image]

And after you have downloaded it install it with:

`dpkg -i packetname.deb`

P.S. Just in case, if something goes wrong with the namely Debian package, you probably will get another chance with Ubuntu packet because they are both `*.deb` debian package format.